# Remove local named ranges within a set of data

Tags: excel, vba

I have Excel VBA code assigned to a button.
I select a cell anywhere inside some data on an Excel sheet (which is arranged such that there is a top row with header names in and data beneath these).
I press this button and it creates local named ranges for each column (i.e. local to the sheet as opposed to a global named range covering the whole spreadsheet), with the name being the column heading.

Given data in Excel:
[image]

If I select any cell within B3:E8 and press the button it would create the local named ranges: "Year", "Sales", "Profit", "Loss" which would cover B4:B8, C4:C8, D4:D8 & E4:E8 respectively.

Note: I'm not working with ListObjects, just data in Excel.

```vb
Sub NameRangeWithTop()
    Dim rng As Range, col, nm
   
    Set rng = Selection.CurrentRegion
    If rng.Rows.Count = 1 Then Exit Sub 'check have a usable area...
   
    For Each col In rng.Columns
        nm = Replace(col.Cells(1), " ", "_")
        ActiveSheet.Names.Add Name:=nm, _
          RefersTo:=col.Offset(1).Resize(col.Cells.Count - 1)
    Next col
End Sub
```

If I change a column heading and then press this button again, there will then be two local named ranges for that column (one with the old header name, one with the new header name).
I'm looking to overwrite existing named ranges for these columns.

I think a separate bit of VBA code could cycle through all the columns in `Selection.CurrentRegion` and delete any local named ranges.
In a similar way to how this code works (then my button would just process both macros, one after the other).

I tried:

```vb
Sub DeleteNamedRangesInWorksheet()
    Dim rng As Range, col
    Dim nm As Name

    Set rng = Selection.CurrentRegion
    If rng.Rows.Count = 1 Then Exit Sub 'check have a usable area...
    
    For Each col In rng.Columns
        For Each nm In ActiveWorksheet.Names
            If nm.RefersTo:=col.Offset(1).Resize(col.Cells.Count - 1) then nm.delete
        Next nm
    Next col

End Sub
```

It gives

> Compile error: Expected: Then or GoTo

on the `:=`

of `If nm.RefersTo:=col.Offset(1).Resize(col.Cells.Count - 1) then nm.delete`.

Comment: You may want to use `Intersect()` for each named range over your selection, and delete if so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So an issue you'll run into with having `dim nm as name` is that you need to reference the `.name` of the name, e.g., `Set labeledRange = Range(namedLabel.Name)` and `labeledRange.Name.Delete`.

I updated some of the dimensions to create a range using the `namedLabel`, then use `Intersect` to determine if any intersect with the `Selection`.

---

Example data:

[image]

Example code:

```
Sub removedNamedRangesIntersectingWithSelection()
    Dim namedLabel As Name
    For Each namedLabel In ActiveWorkbook.Names
        Dim labeledRange As Range:  Set labeledRange = Range(namedLabel.Name)
        If Not Intersect(Selection, labeledRange) Is Nothing Then labeledRange.Name.Delete
    Next namedLabel
End Sub
```

End result from running code:

[image]

Comment: Thanks this works wonderfully. It just needs the region you want to remove the ranges from selected before calling up this sub.